# Can I get LINQ to NHibernate for 2.1.2GA

Tags: linq-to-nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate 2.1.2 GA. We want to use LINQ for NHibernate with it, so I downloaded LINQ for NHibernate 1.0 (the one linked to in the first paragraph of Ayende's blog http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/07/26/nhibernate-linq-1.0-released.aspx) - but it turns out that only works with NHibernate 2.1.0 - so no good to us.

Every search I do for a more up-to-date version seems to lead to links to download NHibernate 3.0.0.Alpha2 - but I can't justify using alpha software in our app, so that's not helpful either.

Is there a suitable LINQ to NHibernate version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, don't worry, found the answer. When you go to download NHibernate at http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/, you have to click on View All Files to see the older versions, including the current GA version. The appropriate LINQ to NHibernate builds are there.